# Azure AD B2C PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify to verify Phone only

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, multi-factor-authentication

In order to avoid users from using VOIP numbers as Phone MFA. I need Azure AD B2C PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify to verify Phone only. We have a check while registering the user to not allow VOIP.But when user is prompted for MFA, AD B2C allow to use the VOIP numbers. Any suggestions

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone allows to both input and verify. I want to restrict user from entering the Phone number.

Answer (score 0):

The `PhoneFactorProtocolProvider` technical profile protocol definition (used by the starterpack that the `mfa-email-or-phone` example builds off of for phone MFA) allows for a metadata field to determine whether the user is allowed to enter a new phone number on the MFA UI or not. You can see this if you look at the [starterpack's base policy file for the version including MFA logins](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/main/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa/TrustFrameworkBase.xml): check the technical profile `PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify` and you will see a metadata item:

```
<Item Key="ManualPhoneNumberEntryAllowed">true</Item>
```

If your phone number input technical profile has this key set to `false` instead of `true` as in the example, the MFA UI will display the phone number provided as an input claim as static text instead of creating an entry form, and the user will not be allowed to edit it. This does mean that if the claim provided for the phone number is empty at runtime, you will get an exception.

With this metadata value set to false, you can provide the user's registered, verified-to-not-be-VOIP phone number to the technical profile as an input and they will not be allowed to enter a different number.

You can also see the [documentation for PhoneFactor technical profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-factor-technical-profile) to see more information about the available metadata fields.